# Elisp - Loading an expression as data from a file

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I am attempting to write a function which, given a file path, will load the contents of that file and append it to a list. The end goal is to have one file for each org-capture template, and to load them from a list of files or an org-table.

My problem is that the load and load-file functions only return t if the load is successful.

What function can I use to return the contents of a file as an expression?

for example, given the file test.el:

```
'("foo" "bar" "baz" "fnord")
```

How can I achieve the following:

```
(mysterious-function "~/test.el")

=> '("foo" "bar" "baz" "fnord")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Load the file into a temporary buffer, then read from the buffer. Get rid of the quote before the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @barmar suggested in the comment:

```lisp
(defun read-from-file (file)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents file)
    (read (current-buffer))))
```

Note that since you are reading and not evaluating, you do not need to put the quote into the file.

If, for some reason, you already have the quote in the file, you should *not* use `eval` to get rid of it because that introduces a security hole (imagine a file which contains the form `(launch-missiles)`).  You should do something like this:

```lisp
(defun my-unquote (form)
  (if (and (eq (first form) 'quote)
           (null (cddr form)))
      (second form)
      form))
```

Comment: If there is already a quote in the file (for what reason ever) and you need to get ride of it you can use `(eval (read-from-file "~/test.el"))`.

Comment: @Tobias: no, this introduces a security hole; please see the edit.

Comment: It depends on the application. `(launch-missiles)` might also be `(start-pigeons)`.

Comment: @Tobias: if that were the application, i.e., the file contained _code_ (as opposed to _data_), it would have been loaded using `load`, not `read-from-file`.

Comment: Not necessarily. It may normally be contain a quoted list and sometimes code that evaluates to a list. Actually, a quoted list is also code that evaluates to a list.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun mysterious-function (filename)
  (setq filename (expand-file-name filename))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents filename)
    (read (current-buffer))))
```

Comment: I don't think you need to call `expand-file-name` explicitly.

Comment: Wasn't sure -- the documentation isn't always clear about which functions require exact filenames and which will expand.